# I am trying to create a bar chat but road block

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I input this code on my terminal, I’m trying to show a football league table with 12 rows and 9 columns. I keep getting valueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape.

```py
Import pandas as pd 
Import numpy as np
Import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Table = pd.read_csv(r’c:\..\..\data\Table.csv’)
plt.bar(x=no.arange(1, 21), height=table[PTS]))
```

Comment: There's a lot of typos in your code snippet, `Import` should be `import`, `no` when you mean `np`? Could you post the code you were running?

Comment: what is a `bar chat` and what has a `road block` to do with python programming

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

table = pd.read_csv(r’c:\..\..\data\Table.csv’)
plt.bar(x=no.arange(1, 13), height=table[PTS]))
```

Comment: Thanks guys. The shape was wrong the np.arange(1, 21) was wrong I had to change to (1, 13) and it worked.

Comment: Quick question: How do I filter rows with nan while trying to plot a chart of a particular column. Wrote the code but my chart keeps bringing out names with nan, I have tried dropna() not working.. I’m using pd to read from a csv file.